# how to use Zindex for different layers in kineticjs?

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

Well I have been trying this small application where I am using two different layers for displaying objects.One for the background(whole stage) and other for the objects displayed on it.so when I change the background on "click" my layer clears before drawing a new one and it gets added to stage but overlapping the other layer.So I need to change background without affecting the other layer.Cant we use "setZIndex" for layers or some other ways...!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use setZIndex after you add to the stage.

You cannot set zIndex without belong to stage. 
The reason is that layer need to find the parent, which is stage.

Thus, add layer to stage first, then set zIndex.

http://jsfiddle.net/bighostkim/QTu8K/

```
stage.add(layer1);
stage.add(layer2);

layer1.setZIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use:

```
stage.add(menuLayer);
menuLayer.setZIndex(10);

stage.add(backgroundLayer);
```

and I was getting `backgroundLayer` in front of `menuLayer` after I drew `backgroundLayer`.

My fix was to set the `backgroundLayer` Z index after it was added to the stage:

```
stage.add(menuLayer);
menuLayer.setZIndex(10);

stage.add(backgroundLayer);
backgroundLayer.setZIndex(0);
```

and suddenly the menu was correctly in front of the background!